# How to get releases for golang/go with go-github

Tags: go, github-api

Learning Go and try to get the release list of golang/go with go-github.

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/google/go-github/github"
    "fmt"
)


func main() {
    client := github.NewClient(nil)

    opt := &github.ListOptions{Page: 2, PerPage: 10}
    releases, rsp, err := client.Repositories.ListReleases("golang", "go", opt)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("\n%+v\n", releases)
    fmt.Printf("\n%+v\n", rsp)

}
```

When I run it, the release list is empty (as below):

```
[]

github.Rate{Limit:60, Remaining:59, Reset:github.Timestamp{2015-12-05 14:47:55 +1100 AEDT}}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

### **Edit:**

Taking a closer look at the Go repository, the releases are actually just tags and not Github releases, that's why it's returning an empty array. Try this:

```
// https://api.github.com/repos/jp9000/obs-studio/releases
releases, rsp, err := client.Repositories.ListReleases("jp9000", "obs-studio", opt)
```

This should correctly return all releases for jp9000's obs-studio repository.

**Original Answer:**

Looking at the docs, the code looks good but this might be an issue with Github's API though. For instance, if you go to https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/releases you get an empty array, but if you search for the tags using https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/tags it lists all tasks without any problem.

And if you go to https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/releases/1 you get a 404. I took these addresses from the Github Developer's page: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository

Comment: Thanks for your reply and it confirm it is not something wrong in my code(kind of). I tried the `golang/go/tags`, it returns tags like `weekly.*`. I think Github should do something to make sure the release created is compliance with their own API

Comment: In bash maybe that could help to get at least latest version `wget -qO- https://github.com/golang/go/tags|sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'|sed '/^\s*$/d'| grep release-branch|awk '{ print $2 }'|grep -v runtime|sort -V|tail -1`